# Bash: Convert lines to array elements

Tags: text-processing

I have log.txt on a macOS system in the following format:

```
#State:      a           b        c
State 1:118.851979 120.668604 84.472229
State 2:126.789728 149.506520 103.196917
State 3:126.379687 149.382354 104.504792
State 4:126.989312 149.372811 103.499396
State 5:126.330563 149.373374 103.956438
State 6:127.238791 149.458749 103.198541
State 7:125.263833 132.658750 88.320687
State 8:126.828000 148.570000 98.722229
State 9:125.042667 147.087896 98.871813
State 10:124.392521 148.656792 103.744938
State 11:115.969084 131.787022 91.721250
State 12:125.385521 135.633751 91.044167
State 13:125.046354 149.432500 104.132167
State 14:126.368354 149.454480 103.942208
State 15:126.454229 149.583730 104.462458
State 16:114.102083 134.422916 93.555625
State 17:127.905604 138.012417 85.556396
State 18:126.362271 149.187688 104.087229
State 19:115.580250 133.450563 93.011062
State 20:125.555854 133.653730 88.441501
```

I need some one liner sollution, which will convert it to python-like array format, similar to:

```
[[118.851979, 120.668604, 84.472229],[126.789728, 149.506520, 103.196917]...[125.555854, 133.653730, 88.441501]]
```

So I take every 3 numbers from each line (2,3 and 4 columns and arrange them in one [] element:

```
[[a, b, c],[a, b, c],[a, b, c]..[a, b , c]]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Do you want to add commas to each element?

Comment: Indeed, I have to add commas between each elements in list, similar to python syntax

Comment: I removed the bash tag since i) you aren't asking for a bash solution here and bash isn't a good tool for the job and ii) based on your [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618491/bash-convert-lines-to-array-elements/618494#comment1156904_618493) you are using macOS and a shell with no `readarray`, so you're almost certainly using zsh and not bash anyway.

Comment: Is there some particular reason you want to use Bash to turn some data into a Python-like format? I mean, if you're going to process it in Python later, why not load the data from that text column format? Or load it into Python and use Python tools to dump it? In any case, you're going to need to use something other than plain Bash, so it might be useful to know what tools you have that can be used.

Comment: If you need to `convert it to python-like array format` (which also indicates a possible future use of this output, Jack) why don't you use 3-4 lines of Python to do this? It's well-documented across the internet, how to save the contents of a file into an array of arrays.

Comment: @terdon: Since the error op got was from bash I believe they are using bash but bash v3.2 which does not have readarray.

Comment: @jesse_b ah yes, you're right, the error did mention bash. Nevertheless, this isn't a bash thing, so I think I was right to remove the tag.

Comment: don't worry, it is just an exercise.. next one will be enterily python version .. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `awk` approach:

```
$ awk -F'[ :]' 'BEGIN{printf "["}NR>1{printf "[%s,%s,%s],",$3,$4,$5}END{printf "]\n"}' file | sed 's/,\]$/]/'
[[118.851979,120.668604,84.472229],[126.789728,149.506520,103.196917],[126.379687,149.382354,104.504792],[126.989312,149.372811,103.499396],[126.330563,149.373374,103.956438],[127.238791,149.458749,103.198541],[125.263833,132.658750,88.320687],[126.828000,148.570000,98.722229],[125.042667,147.087896,98.871813],[124.392521,148.656792,103.744938],[115.969084,131.787022,91.721250],[125.385521,135.633751,91.044167],[125.046354,149.432500,104.132167],[126.368354,149.454480,103.942208],[126.454229,149.583730,104.462458],[114.102083,134.422916,93.555625],[127.905604,138.012417,85.556396],[126.362271,149.187688,104.087229],[115.580250,133.450563,93.011062],[125.555854,133.653730,88.441501]]
```

Or, a little more legible:

```
awk -F'[ :]' 'BEGIN{
                printf "["
              }
              NR>1{
                printf "[%s,%s,%s],",$3,$4,$5
              }
              END{
                printf "]\n"
              }' file | sed 's/,\]$/]/'
```

**Explanation**

- `awk -F'[ :]'`: set awk's input field separator to a space OR a `:`.
- `BEGIN{printf "["}`: print the opening `[`.
- `NR>1{printf "[%s,%s,%s],",$3,$4,$5}` : for every line except the first, print the 3rd, 4th and 5th fields within a `[ ]` and separated by a comma.
- `END{printf "]\n"}`: print the closing `]`.
- `sed 's/,\]$/]/'`: remove the last `,` added before the END block.

Comment: Thank you so much! One question how it would be possible to round each number mooved to the list via AWK expression, something like [%s.3f,%s.3f,%s.3f], when I need to keep only 3 numbers after . ?

Comment: @user3470313 please try to include all of your requirements in the original question so we don't need to do this sort of thing. But yes, you can just do `printf "[%.3f,%.3f,%.3f],",$3,$4,$5`. No `%s` (that's for strings), just `%.3f` (f for floats).

Comment: Right, Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `jq` to format the data as a JSON array-of-arrays:

```
jq -nRc '[inputs | split(":")] | .[1:] | map(.[1] | split(" ") | map(tonumber))' <log.txt
```

If you want rounded values, you can replace

```
map(tonumber)
```

with

```
map(tonumber | . *1000 | round | . /1000)
```

i.e.

```
$ jq -nRc '[inputs | split(":")] | .[1:] | map(.[1] | split(" ") | map(tonumber | .*1000 |
round | ./1000))' <log.txt
[[118.852,120.669,84.472],[126.79,149.507,103.197],[126.38,149.382,104.505],[126.989,149.373,103.499],[126.331,149.373,103.956],[127.239,149.459,103.199],[125.264,132.659,88.321],[126.828,148.57,98.722],[125.043,147.088,98.872],[124.393,148.657,103.745],[115.969,131.787,91.721],[125.386,135.634,91.044],[125.046,149.433,104.132],[126.368,149.454,103.942],[126.454,149.584,104.462],[114.102,134.423,93.556],[127.906,138.012,85.556],[126.362,149.188,104.087],[115.58,133.451,93.011],[125.556,133.654,88.442]]
```

Answer (score 2):

So... both of these answers are good, but make me really nervous. Let me explain.

`awk` is as "Unix" as it gets. However, it is unwise to assume you'll know *which* "awk" you'll get; all of which are very powerful but very incompatible extensions of either the original awk (which *you* will, in fact most likely get, but only on a Mac), or one of gawk, mawk, nawk auk... or, um, perl. To name a few.

AWK is also itself its own fully Turing-complete language, but it resembles shell command language (i.e., what you call "bash") a little too much for my liking to call inline for something like this. A single misplaced single quote and suddenly your AWK commands are executing in the shell, but doing something completely different. Its also a bit heavy handed for what *would* be a relatively simple task like this... AWK can itself natively do nested associative arrays, and has native trigonometric functions that it can do on native 32-bit floating point numbers. No Python necessary.

The `jq` solution is **awesome**... I feel pretty stupid—I fully didn't realize that `jq` had the ability to *read in* to its native JSON like it can read *out*... but of course it can! I'm not sure what `jq` **can't do**... I recently was using a  wrapper, I forget what it was called, which was able to easily and safely handle XML Xpath, with the same  notation, and then give the same data back with key-value reversed, but in YAML. Amazing. However, `jq` is a tool that fundamentally is based on **JSON** — (a data serialization format invented by Douglas Crockford), and it likewise doesn't sound *exactly* like what you are looking for, as: 1. Although they look similar, Python data structures are *not* JSON, and if you want to safely handle JSON in Python, you need to use the the `json` module to ensure the deserialization is handled properly. etc. And in JSON nesting brackets like that, `[[],]` has a whole different meaning than in Python: its a way of explicitly saying in JavaScript *Object* Notation that" this is *specifically* an Array, with nested Array(s), and not *Objects*, which use braces, `{}`, not brackets, `[]`. It also will not, for example, handle a hanging comma after the last nested Array; whereas Python usually will.

If this question *were* simply about **text processing**, as it is tagged, this is where I'd point out that *almost all* modern shells can do this this type of text processing without calling a single external program—you can pipe the file to the `read` builtin which takes a single variable as an arguement (usuall used in a `while` loop, and the variable is traditionally called `line`, i.e.,`while read line < file; do`), and then in your do block, you can field split each line by passing as an argument to a function, which will treat it like the special variables `$@` and its components `$1`, `$2`, `$3`... etc. And if you don't want it field split, you can use `$*`. This is (usually), actually, the only complex data type the shell has; it doesn't know or treat anything as a number otherwise, except with (rudimentary) arithmetic expansion, which looks like `$(($x + 4))`, or by calling an external or tool or an extension.

But it doesn't seem like that *is* what you are asking, and I think the best "answer" above, is from @thanasisp, which I'm going to paraphrase as "if this is going to be used in Python, why are you not just using Python?" or what on earth do you mean by a "python-like array format"?

Firstly, the phrase "python-like array format" is more or less meaningless. While the nested-brackets-with-commas format can be loosely called **C**-like (**C** is the language from which this came, and why it exists in Python, and JSON, and many other languages), each language (or serialization format) has many subtle but very important differences in implementation. Moreover, there is no other language or language feature I would fairly call "Python-like", except for Python. Python is also the only language that I would say is fairly also called *unlike* Python, because Python is completely incompatible with Python, depending on if you mean what is today called "Python 2", which has largely been banned/forcibly deprecated, or the current "Python", originally a fork ,which has variously been known as Python 3000, Py3k, Python3, but has (after years of acrimonious debate, is usually what is meant by "Python".

Most critically, in all versions of Python, you have specified perfectly valid data such as "1:118.851979", a perfectly valid construction... but one that doesn't do what I think you want; the colon is the "slice" operator. However, in Python, it is usually perfectly acceptable to implicitly inline an operation like in an otherwise structured variable assignment, and it is also typically ok to inline code elsewhere. In other languages, however, this might be interpreted as a number that is a ratio; in some (C++, etc.) colons indicate object or template selectors, and in a shell, it is the null function. Moreover, the example you cite is also perfectly valid, but again, I believe it means something completely different that what I assume you *actually* mean—`[[a, b, c],[a, b, c],[a, b, c]...` is a construction comprised of references to three previously defined variables, named "a", "b", or "c", followed by two more references to these same variables in a row. *Is* that what you mean?

he examples you have
I know this might come off asBut they really